# Alternator dying so junk car?

Tags: battery, nissan, alternator, charging

The alternator store rounded the bolt on my alternator so I can’t get it off my 2004 g35x. I changed the belts (there are two one for ac and one for alternator) since I did that the car has a voltage when in park of approx 14Vdc if I turn the ac on it can maintain around 13.9v to 14v however that is with the blower at lowest setting if I go to the highest setting as we are in the summer months it quickly starts to fall and in order to maintain the 14v I must have my engine rpm at least 1000.

My question is can I just keep monitoring the voltage and use the car or should I be looking to get rid of it. (I am not interested in spending loads of cash as it’s a 15 year old car at this point)

The other question I have is would it fail completely or does the charging rate get progressively less until I need to redline her to charge the battery?

Comment: Get the alternator store to replace that bolt... They damaged it...

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) 15 years isn't an old car these days, 2) Why would you junk a car over a 50-cent bolt that can be extracted and replaced in 10 minutes by any competent DIYer?

Comment: What makes you think it's "dying" at all?

Comment: @SolarMike What makes you think they won't make things worse through negligence given that they were okay with treating OP like this?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Is that the best you can come up with? Nothing useful? The places I go to, they will sort their mistakes even before I find them and say "we stripped X and have sorted it at no cost"...

Comment: @SolarMike Is this "alternator store" one of the places you go to and can vouch for? A word of caution is often times very useful. Count your blessings that you haven't had to deal with unreal levels of ineptitude.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Are you making assumptions about my location? Big error... I have had to, and still, deal with levels of ineptitude you probably have not come across yet... Often from enthusiastic amateurs who have little knowledge but a massive over estimation of their capabilities... They get to pay for their mistakes...

Comment: ok lets see here the alternator store claimed it was like that when they tried so thats a court case to prove them wrong, I dont know where you live user1573 but here in NYC no bolts cost 50cents and certainly no alternator bolts but that is not the issue, the issue is getting it out as the bolt is rusted in place. if that can be done great, the alternator is dying as I took my battery to the store and they tested it and the alternator store claimed they tested the alternator and it was dying and no i cannot vouch for them MonkeyZeus.

Comment: @infinitelyfocused From your replies, it sounds like you don't like the car, and just want a reason to junk it rather than try a simple repair. So junk it. There are many people who'd take it off your hands, even with the problem.

Comment: I honestly don't know what an alternator store is exactly but any competent mechanic can remove a rounded bolt. I would advise against going back to the same place that rounded your bolt and told you that it was already like that. Maybe you meant to say auto parts store like AutoZone or Wal-Mart in some cases? If not then was it a repair shop?

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-a-Broken-Bolt

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No I don't mean a parts store like AutoZone I mean an alternator store that sells alternators exactly! and no I did not go back to them they clearly did not have the skills to repair.@petecon you are partially correct i do love the car but it has a few other issues associated with it being old and living in a high salt environment, both back shock mounts are rusted and the front passenger side has a rattle i have not figured out as yet so I am trying to make the best decision of do i dump more cash into it or just call it a day and sell her, both will be tough decisions for me.

Comment: @Infinitelyfocused Well that is simply interesting. I've never heard of a store dedicated to alternators; NYC must be an interesting place. For now I would recommend going around to a shop or two and simply ask them "How much for you to remove and replace this rounded bolt?" Once that is out of the way, hopefully the next store/shop does not round it again.

Answer (score 22):

A rounded bolt is not a reason to junk a car. The numbers you're quoting sound fine for an alternator; if it was below 12V, I'd be worried. If you're still concerned, take the car to a spares store and ask them to check the battery and alternator.

When it does come time to change the alternator, getting the bolt off would not take a lot of extra time; there are several ways to do it.

Comment: Several, *several* ways to do it ...

Comment: In fact, a picture of said bolt might be a great follow up question....

Comment: Below 13V would be cause for worry (unable to charge), but 13.9 or even 13.4 is perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't think a picture is even necessary.  People have dealt with stripped, fully rusted bolts. This is not a big deal. Any remotely competent mechanic can get that thing off readily.

Comment: @nelson remotely competent mechanics are harder to find in NYC than the end of a rainbow and fighting off quack mechanics drains more energy than kryptonite.

Answer (score 7):

I have seen somebody spot-weld a short bolt to the rounded nut they are having trouble removing.  It's cheap and quick if the equipment is on hand.

Comment: thats a great suggestion. I will certainly ask a mechanic about doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Go to whatever chain auto parts store is nearby they will test the alternator, likely for free. That at least would answer your question about needing to replace it.